# Can we combine Off-Policy with On-Policy Algorithms?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, open-ai, off-policy-methods, on-policy-methods

**On-Policy Algorithms** like PPO directly maximize the performance objective or an approximation of it. They tend to be quite stable and reliable but are often sample inefficient. **Off-Policy Algorithms** like TD3 improve the sample inefficiency by reusing data collected with previous policies, but they tend to be less stable. (Source: [Kinds of RL Algorithms - Spinning up - OpenAI](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro2.html))

Looking at learning curves comparing SOTA algorithms, we see that off-policy algorithms quickly improve performance at the training's beginning. Here [an example](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/bench.html#walker2d-tensorflow-versions):
[image: 3M timestep benchmark of different algorithms for Walker2d-v3]

Can we start training off-policy and after some time use the learned and quickly improved policy to init the policy network of an on-policy algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DRL nanodegree in Udacity, the instructor says it is possible to combine on- and off-policy learning and suggests the following paper where this has been done: [Q-Prop: Sample-Efficient Policy Gradient with An Off-Policy Critic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02247.pdf) (ICLR 2017). 
Citing the paper:

> The core idea is to use the first-order Taylor expansion of the critic
>   as a control variate, resulting in an analytical gradient term through
>   the critic and a Monte Carlo policy gradient term consisting of the
>   residuals in advantage approximations. The method helps unify policy
>   gradient and actor-critic methods: it can be seen as using the
>   off-policy critic to reduce variance in policy gradient or using
>   on-policy Monte Carlo returns to correct for bias in the critic
>   gradient.

The authors provide an open source implementation of it in https://github.com/shaneshixiang/rllabplusplus

There is a follow-up paper by the same authors also addressing this problem: Interpolated Policy Gradient: [Merging On-Policy and Off-Policy Gradient Estimation for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6974-interpolated-policy-gradient-merging-on-policy-and-off-policy-gradient-estimation-for-deep-reinforcement-learning.pdf) (NIPS 2017).

The Related Work section in both papers might be also worth looking at.

Comment: Dear @user5093249, thank you very much for your detailed and definitely interesting answer. I'll definitely have a look at the papers. I'm especially interested in combining existing algorithms (like TD3 and PPO) instead of developing new ones that combine on- and off-policy approaches.

Comment: @RayWalker your approach seems to be in line with what the authors suggest. In fact, in the first paper, they state that "since Q-Prop uses both on-policy policy updates and off-policy critic learning, it can take advantage of prior work along both lines of research". They implemented it on top of TRPO-GAE for example.

Comment: Ok great, thank you very much for the additional information. I've now had a look at both abstracts and accepted your answer. It very well answers the main question in the topic.  And the Q-Prop paper just jumped to the top of my reading list : )